# how to find deleted records oracle questions

Tags: oracle

Suppose in one table 1000 records are there randomly some are records are deleted in oracle. how to find deleted records.tell the query to find the deleted records.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look into flashback query.  You can find the state of the table in a certain date/time range if still in UNDO.

Answer (score 1):

You can use flashback.
If you remember the date when the table was in your database you can do like an exemple :
FLASHBACK TABLE table_name TO TIMESTAMP 
      TO_TIMESTAMP('2017-06-13 22:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS');

Or if you know the SCN number :
FLASHBACK TABLE Table_name TO SCN 123456;

Or you can check recyclebin

I hope i helped you

Comment: The recyclebin holds dropped objects, not deleted rows.

Answer (score 0):

There is no query to find deleted records. If there is an identifying column populated by a monotonically incrementing sequence it might be possible to find the missing values. But that would be a best guess, not a guaranteed set.

The correct solution is to put auditing or journalling in place, so that a shadow history of the table is maintained elsewhere.